# MYSqli update last row

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am trying to set a trigger in mysqli where it after I insert a row  in

```
    tblallocation

       (AllocID,
        AssetID,
        AssetName ,
        AssetModel,
        Custody,
        Location,
        Discontinued,
        DiscDate    
        DateAlloc,
        ReturnStockDate)
```

the trigger updates tblassets and sets `allocated= true`

```
   (assetID,
    Asset,
    Brand,
    Model,
    Serial,
    AssetCondition,
    description,
    Location,
Allocated)
```

i am writing the trigger as follows and its not working :

```
CREATE TRIGGER `change to allocated` AFTER INSERT ON `tblallocation`
  FOR EACH ROW update tblassets SET allocated=1  
  where tblassets.AssetID =tblallocation.MAX(AssetID)
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no possibility that another insert is made in the meantime you can go ahead and use the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function provided by MYSQL to get the unique id of the last inserted row. (for more reference please check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html)

However if this doesn't suit you then you can use a subquery instead of tblallocation.MAX(AssetID).

The subquery should be something like

```
SELECT AssetID from tblallocation order by AssetID desc LIMIT 1;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer i tried the below didnt work update tblassets SET allocated=1  where tblassets.assetID =(SELECT AssetID from tblallocation order by AssetID desc LIMIT 1)

Comment: Can you provide more details about the error you get, as well as create table for relevant tables. 
I'm not sure why are you using the syntax FOR EACH ROW?

Comment: ok i am working on an asset management program using php so on the first page you have assets that are not allocated which means tblassets.allocated=false, once on the second page i allocate the asset it should go update tblassets and set allocated to true where tblallocation.assetid of this asset that has been allocated = tblassets.assetid thats the purpose so when i created first trigger it updated all allocated to  true.

Comment: and in mysqli  triggers u cant but use for each row thats how it works .

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all i have found the solution.

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `change to allocated`;CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `change to allocated` AFTER INSERT ON `tblallocation` FOR EACH ROW update tblassets SET allocated=1 where tblassets.assetID =new.assetid